# What does exec $SHELL -l do?

Tags: mac, unix

By accident, I ran the command

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

in my terminal, and it changed how my prompt looks

```
Macintosh:~ myname$ exec $SHELL -l
Macintosh-2:~ myname$ cd
```

i.e. there's a "-2" after Macintosh

```
Macintosh:~ myname$
Macintosh-2: myname$
```

I'm not sure if this might be responsible for some problems I'm having on my system.

I'm trying to use Ruby 1.9.3 on my system, which I installed with Rbenv.

```
rbenv version
1.9.3-p327
```

However, when I try to install gems, i'm getting an error message that they require at least ruby 1.9.2, so I'm assuming that the machine is still using the version of Ruby that comes with my Mac. I tried to fix this by

```
gem install bundle
rbenv rehash
bundle install
```

but I keep getting the same error message about needing at least Ruby 1.9.2, so I'm wondering if the effect of running `exec $SHELL -l` is preventing gems from installing for some reason.

Comment: What shell are you using?  (The most likely answer is `bash`, but `csh`, `ksh`, and `zsh` are a few other possibilities.)  What do you see if you type `echo $SHELL`?  (The answer to this question will probably give you the answer to the first question.)  What happens if you logout and login again (or start a new shell window; whichever is applicable)?  What “problems” are you having?

Comment: @Scott I'm on a Mac, mountain lion. I'll explain my problem in an update to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`$SHELL` refers to your shell (command interpreter).  Most shells recognize the `–l` (lowercase L) option to mean that it is a “login shell”, which primarily means that it reads and processes extra command files (e.g., `csh` always reads `.cshrc`, but if it is a “login shell”, it also reads `.login`).  You have started a new shell processes running and told it to act like “login shell”.

Some shells (I believe `bash` is one) keep track of hierarchical shell processes and let the user display the depth, or level.  This is often incorporated into the shell prompt, as in:

> *(prompt string)*`$` **`pwd`**
>   `/dir1`
>    *(prompt string)*`$` **`$SHELL`**
>    *(prompt* `2` *string)*`$` **`cd ../dir2`**                *# Note that
>   the shell level is*`2`*,*
>    *(prompt* `2` *string)*`$` **`rm *`**                            *# indicating that
>   you are in a new shell process.*
>    *(prompt* `2` *string)*`$` **`exit`**
>    *(prompt string)*`$` **`pwd`**                                   *# Note return
>   to original shell process.*
>   `/dir1`

This shouldn’t have anything to do with your problem with RubyGems.

Comment: thanks, but I can't get it back to the original shell level. I tried 'exit' and it logs out but when i open a new terminal window it's the shell level 2 again